# SignalR 2 - not all messages sent from server received by client when multiple instances of hub

Tags: angularjs, azure, signalr, signalr-hub

**EDIT:**

I've been doing some additional testing, and this appears to only happen when I'm running multiple instances of the web role hosting the SignalR hub (I'm using a azure service bus backplane). When I'm running a single instance of the hub, I see all messages come through to the client. When I'm running multiple instances, I get these symptoms:

- Logging from server indicates that all messages were sent
- Logging from client indicates that only some messages were received
- Looking at server traffic with wireshark while remoted into the cloud service on azure captures only the messages that the client receives

My suspicion is that the client holds a connection to a single instance of the web role and that when messages happen to originate from the web role to which the client isn't connected, the client can't receive it even when it is broadcast to the correct SignalR connection.

Anyone else having a problem with missing messages when running multiple instances of a SignalR hub hosted in a web site? Is there a way around this problem?

---

I've got an asynchronous process started via an API call from a javascript client that finishes in one or more messages sent via our SignalR hub back to that client. It appears that not all messages sent from the SignalR hub are received by the javascript client. Below is the flow along with logging messages that I receive:

1. The client connects to our SignalR hub then immediately calls a subscribe method that associates the current connection id with our internal user identifier:

   - Websocket opened
   - Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332 and a connection lost timeout of 20000.
   - Triggering client hub event 'subscribed' on hub 'EventHub'
   - Client subscribed to event hub: 5539368b-5f82-48bd-8ed9-2c5bed3caefa [this is the indicator that the back end associated the given connection id with the user id]
2. I start the back end process that should result in two messages being sent back to this client. Logging from within the SignalR hub indicates that two messages were being sent (message lists all connections associated with the given internal user id--I've got old connections in our cache I haven't cleaned out):

   - event hub broadcasting control action updated to user 124 for control action 120 on connections 5aaea44a-7810-45b5-8119-3ff1fe613d63, 4be9ca16-1e31-42bf-91db-798b757a381c, 5f9f9962-4f8b-4712-929e-c943e28ca91f, de7135ba-4e16-4e9e-9c38-e8f78ed59636, 82e900d1-005e-4bff-95d0-3737632b4671, 0cc273f9-04aa-4570-8cd7-993876219e52, 2b6db0f7-ab0c-41d3-beb5-3b312107a923, 5539368b-5f82-48bd-8ed9-2c5bed3caefa **[note connection id from above is included in list]**
   - event hub broadcasting control action updated to user 124 for control action 128 on connections 5aaea44a-7810-45b5-8119-3ff1fe613d63, 4be9ca16-1e31-42bf-91db-798b757a381c, 5f9f9962-4f8b-4712-929e-c943e28ca91f, de7135ba-4e16-4e9e-9c38-e8f78ed59636, 82e900d1-005e-4bff-95d0-3737632b4671, 0cc273f9-04aa-4570-8cd7-993876219e52, 2b6db0f7-ab0c-41d3-beb5-3b312107a923, 5539368b-5f82-48bd-8ed9-2c5bed3caefa **[note connection id from above is included in list]**
3. On the client, I'm logging when the method is invoked as a result of a message being sent, and I see:

   - received controlActionUpdated message from event hub with model: controlActionId 120

**Sometimes the client gets all the messages sent from the hub, but more often, it's missing one or two.** Relevant code snippets are below:

**CLIENT:**

We use a generalized eventing service in angularjs. Consumer of events connects and subscribes to a list of events as follows:

`eventing.initialize(['controlActionUpdated', 'subscribed']);`

The service looks like this:

```
var cn;
var hubProxy;
var eventsToHandle = [];

var initialize = function(events){
    for(var index = 0; index < events.length; index++){
        if(eventsToHandle.indexOf(events[index]) == -1){
            eventsToHandle.push(events[index]);
        }
    }
    connect();
}

//call this to connect to the eventing hub and set up client-side receiving methods
var connect = function(){
    cn = $.hubConnection('https://events.xxx.com/');
    cn.logging = true;

    hubProxy = cn.createHubProxy('eventHub');

    //subscribe to all events currently indicated to be handled
    for(var index = 0; index < eventsToHandle.length; index++){
        listen(eventsToHandle[index]);
    }

    hubProxy.on('subscribed', function (model) {
        console.log('Client subscribed to event hub: ' + model);
    });

    cn.qs = { "optiAuthToken" : authentication.getAuthToken() };
    cn.start().done(function(){
        //subscribe to events for this specific user
        hubProxy.invoke('subscribe');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('connectedToHub');
    });
}


var listen = function(eventName){
    hubProxy.on(eventName, function(model){
        $rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, model);
    });
}
```

The receiving method to the `$rootScope.$broadcast(eventName, model);` call above is:

```
$scope.$on('controlActionUpdated', function (event, model) {
    console.log('received controlActionUpdated message from event hub with model: controlActionId ' + model.controlActionId);
    [further code omitted]
```

**SERVER:**

This method calls our cache to get the list of connections for the executingUserID. If it finds at least one, it sends a message to that list of connections.

```
public async Task MyControlActionUpdated(ControlActionEventModel model, int executingUserID)
{
    EventingConnectionDetails[] currentConnections = await cache.GetCurrentEventHubConnections(executingUserID);
    if (currentConnections.Length > 0)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("event hub broadcasting control action updated to user {0} for control action {1} on connections {2}",
            executingUserID, model.controlActionId, string.Join(", ", currentConnections.Select(c => c.ConnectionID).Distinct()));
        Clients.Clients(currentConnections.Select(c => c.ConnectionID).Distinct().ToList()).controlActionUpdated(model);
    }
    else
    {
        Trace.TraceError("attempt to broadcast control action updated to user {0} for control action {1} failed due to no connections",
            executingUserID, model.controlActionId);
    }
```

}

I've looked around for other people complaining of the client missing messages from the server but haven't found anything. Does anyone have any ideas why messages logged as sent from the server are not logged as received on the client?

I'm using SignalR 2.0 hosted in a web role in Azure with a service bus backplane. Client is AngularJS version 1.2.14.

Comment: Where are you calling MyControlActionUpdated?

Comment: It's called at the end of the async process--called from a different service hosted in an Azure worker role.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the service bus backplane was not actually working due to an incorrect configuration on my part (I was calling UseServiceBus on my dependency resolver first then setting the dependency resolver to my unity resolver for DI).

Note to self: check traffic through service bus topic first before trying to dig deeper. :)